# Prove Newton's Formulas

Tags: calculus

Assume that the $n$-th degree polynomial
$$g(x) =x^n+a_{n−1}x^{n−1}+a_{n−2}x^{n−2}+···+a_1x+a_0$$
has $n$ distinct roots $\xi_1, \xi_2, ..., \xi_n$.
Prove Newton’s formulas: 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\xi^k_i}{g'(\xi_i)}=\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
&0,&\ 0\leq k \leq n-2,\ k \in \mathbb{N^*}\\
&1,&\ k = n-1
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
Hint given: use partial fraction expansion of $\frac{x^k}{g(x)}$.

But it seems that I still cannot figure out the answer.

Comment: $\frac{x^k}{g(x)}=\frac{A_1}{x-\zeta_1}+...+\frac{A_n}{x-\zeta_n}$. Multiplying by $x-\zeta_i$ and evaluating at $x=\zeta_i$ you get that $\frac{\zeta_i^k}{g'(\zeta_i)}=A_i$. Now sum all fractions on the right and look at the term of degree $n-1$ in the numerator and compare with the term of the same degree in the numerator $x^k$ of the left fraction.

Comment: Please check the argument of $g'$ in the denominator. Should not it be $\xi_i$ rather than $\xi_i^k$?